# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{..} : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

Я пытаюсь создать некоторое количество кнопок и задать им параметры, затем запускать другую активность с параметром, зависящим от номера кнопки. Почему-то при запуске Quest activity вылезает это:

```
05-21 20:24:52.172: W/dalvikvm(17877): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419ad930)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thegameoflife/com.example.thegameoflife.Quest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3455)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3327)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3303)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.example.thegameoflife.Quest.onCreate(Quest.java:101)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
05-21 20:24:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    ... 11 more
```

Вот код активности Quest:

```
public class Quest extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    int displayHeight;
    int displayWidth;
    int allQuests=0;
    int aviliable=0;
    String avi="1";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        int i;
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         this.displayHeight = intent.getIntExtra("hei", 0);
         this.displayWidth = intent.getIntExtra("wid", 0);
         String params="";
        try {
            params = getStringFromAssetFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         this.allQuests=Integer.parseInt(params);
File myF = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/data/","quest.txt");
            if(!myF.exists())
            {
                try 
                {
                    String str = "1";
                    myF.createNewFile();
                        FileWriter fWr = new FileWriter(myF);                   
                        fWr.write(str);
                        fWr.flush();
                        fWr.close();      
                }
                catch (Throwable t) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }      
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                        FileReader fRd = new FileReader(myF);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fRd);
                        String str;
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                            buffer.append(str);
                        }  
                        fRd.close();
                        avi=buffer.toString();
                }
                catch (Throwable t) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception: " + t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }      

            }
             this.aviliable=Integer.parseInt(avi);
             setContentView(R.layout.quest);
         LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         lParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

         Button [] btn= new Button [aviliable+1];
         for(i=1;i<=aviliable;i++){
             lin.addView(btn[i-1],lParams);
             btn[i-1].setText(Integer.toString(i));
             btn[i-1].setTag(Integer.toString(i));
             btn[i-1].setOnClickListener(this);
         }
         lin.addView(btn[aviliable],lParams);
         btn[aviliable].setText("Home");
         int a=aviliable+1;
         btn[aviliable].setTag(Integer.toString(a));
         btn[aviliable].setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    String getStringFromAssetFile() throws IOException
    {
        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open("stat.txt");
        String s = convertStreamToString(is);
        is.close();
        return s;
    }

    public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
            throws IOException {
        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {        
            return "";
        }
    }   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String s=v.getTag().toString();
        int num=Integer.parseInt(s);
        if(num==aviliable+1){
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(Quest.this,QuestWorkingScreen.class);
            i.putExtra("hei", displayHeight);
            i.putExtra("wid", displayWidth);
            i.putExtra("num",num);
            i.putExtra("max",allQuests);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
```

Я думаю, что ошибка здесь:

```
File myF = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/data/","quest.txt");
            if(!myF.exists())
            {
                try 
                {

                    String str = "1";
                    myF.createNewFile();


                        FileWriter fWr = new FileWriter(myF);                   
                        fWr.write(str);
                        fWr.flush();
                        fWr.close();      
                }
                catch (Throwable t) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
            else
            {
                try {
                        FileReader fRd = new FileReader(myF);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fRd);
                        String str;
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                            buffer.append(str);
                        }  
                        fRd.close();
                        avi=buffer.toString();
                }
                catch (Throwable t) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception: " + t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }      

            }
```

Или здесь:

```
         setContentView(R.layout.quest);
         LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         lParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

         Button [] btn= new Button [aviliable+1];
         for(i=1;i<=aviliable;i++){
             lin.addView(btn[i-1],lParams);
             btn[i-1].setText(Integer.toString(i));
             btn[i-1].setTag(Integer.toString(i));
             btn[i-1].setOnClickListener(this);
         }
         lin.addView(btn[aviliable],lParams);
         btn[aviliable].setText("Home");
         int a=aviliable+1;
         btn[aviliable].setTag(Integer.toString(a));
         btn[aviliable].setOnClickListener(this);
```

В файле stat.txt одно число.
101-я строка:

```
btn[aviliable].setText("Home");
```

Comment: Я думаю, нужно указать конкретную строку, которая вызывает падение, а не два куска кода с предположением, что может где то здесь... Никто не будет высчитывать эту несчастную 101-ую строку из вашего листинга

Comment: > at com.example.thegameoflife.Quest.onCreate(Quest.java:101)    
Что находится на 101 строке?

Comment: btn[aviliable].setText("Home");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка во второй части. Посмотрите внимательно, вы создали массив: `Button [] btn= new Button [aviliable+1];`, но затем нигде не присвоили значения его элементам, поэтому всего его элементы — null.

P.S. Я потратил несколько минут на чтение и разбор этого ужасного когда. Пожалуйста, делайте это в следующий сами, тем более, что писали его вы. Не можете разобрать — перепишите.

Comment: А чему должно быть равно значение какого-нибудь элемента из этого массива? Строка, добавленная мной в for позже: btn[i-1]=new Button(this); ничегошеньки не делает.

Comment: @IvanMotorin да, там должен быть Button. Он должен быть перед `lin.addView()`. Как вы его создадите - через `new Button()`, или через `LayoutInflater.inflate()` - это вам решать.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался. После цикла for нужно было также объявить кнопку btn[aviliable]=new Button(this); . Правда, я теперь ловлю другие ошибки, но это уже совсем другая история :)